# ¿Como mostrar datos procesados de una consulta en una vista xhtml con JSF?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces

Estoy realizando una aplicación que consulta medicamentos y necesito conocer cuantos tienen reacción positiva y negativa. Donde recibo el resulset de mi consulta hago una serie de comparaciones para obtener el numero total de respuestas positivas a *X* medicamento y de sus respuestas negativas.
Pero los datos de numero de positivos o numero de negativos no están en mi clase DTO por lo que no puedo mostrarlo en la vista xhtml.

```
public class comentarioDTO{
  private String polaridad;
  private String comentario;
  private String enfermedad;
  private String medicamento;
}



public ArrayList<ComentariosDTO> TipoEnfermedad(String enfermedad) {
    if (enfermedad.equalsIgnoreCase("Hepatitis")) {
        int hpos = 0, hneg = 0, rpos = 0, rneg = 0, bpos = 0, bneg = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < hep.size(); j++) {
            String enf = (String) hep.get(j);
            for (Comentarios oC : oRepoComent.buscaMedicamento(enf)) {
                oConsLocal = new ComentariosDTO();
            }
            oConsLocal.setPolaridad(oC.getPolaridad());
            oConsLocal.setComentario(oC.getComentario());
            oConsLocal.setEnfermedad(oC.getEnfermedad());
            oConsLocal.setMedicamento(enf);

            if (enf.compareToIgnoreCase("Harvoni") == 0) {
                if (oC.getPolaridad().compareToIgnoreCase("Positivo") == 0) {
                    hpos++;
                } else {
                    hneg++;
                }
            } else {
                if (enf.compareToIgnoreCase("ribavirina") == 0) {
                    if (oC.getPolaridad().compareToIgnoreCase("Positivo") == 0) {
                        rpos++;
                    } else {
                        rneg++;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (enf.compareToIgnoreCase("boceprevir") == 0) {
                        if (oC.getPolaridad().compareToIgnoreCase("Positivo") == 0) {
                            bpos++;
                        } else {
                            bneg++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Y ¿cuál es el problema en añadir estos campos al DTO? Crea las variables de positivos y negativos como campos, no como variables locales, y según iteras ya les estás dando valores.

Comment: Gracias, lo he resuelto de esa forma

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev considera publicar una respuesta

Comment: @RuslanLópez, no veo mucho sentido publicar una respuesta. Kary dice que lo ha solucionado...

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev la mayoría pensaría igual que tú, a fin de cuentas quien decide eso eres tú. Pero la reputación en este sitio puede algún día ser tan útil como en el sitio en inglés y [Ayudarte a conseguir empleo y algunos otros beneficios](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254257/professional-benefits-of-building-reputation-on-so),

Comment: Adicionalmente en la ecnuesta de stackoverflow del año 2015 puedes ver que plantean una [posible correlación entre el salario y la reputación](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2015#work-compensation-so).

Comment: @RuslanLópez, publicaré una respuesta pero no por las razones que expones. Tengo mi trabajo y no espero que me consideren/contraten por mi reputación en algún site como este. Tampoco negociar mi sueldo en base a lo mismo. Y si llega este día, seguro que será después de mi jubilación y yo no lo veré. De todos modos publico una respuesta para no parecerme a los demás y, sobre todo, para que quede el hilo más recogido. Y, ahora en serio, crees que Kary se pasará por aquí una vez resuelto su problema? Saludos.

Comment: No, y no creo que lo hayas hecho por ayudar a Kary en particular. Pero bueno, yo si me he hallado a empresas que me hallan por mi perfil de stackoverflow ya mí me gusta porque aumenta mi presencia en internet, ayudo gente, y encuentro respuestas a problemas con que me he enfrentado y no recuerdo por ser algo desmemoriado.

Comment: Pues te equivocas y mucho, @RuslanLópez. Busca todas mis respuestas en el site (incluido el de inglés que son menos) y verás que todas, incluidas las que han recibido votos negativos, están enfocadas a la ayuda. La reputación me provocas sudores en ciertos atributos de mi cuerpo. Sí, escribí para ayudar a Kary, aunque no te lo creas. Y por otro lado es de agradecer que Kary se ha pasado por el hilo una vez solucionado su problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes añadir los campos que te interesan al DTO. Algo así:

```
public class comentarioDTO{
  private String polaridad;
  private String comentario;
  private String enfermedad;
  private String medicamento;
  private int hpos;

  // getters & setters

  // por facilitar el trabajo yo haría un método de añadir
  public void addHpos() {
      hpos++;
  }
}
```

Supongo que esta clase se debe llamar `ComentariosDTO` y no `comentarioDTO` pero esto ya es cosa tuya...

Y luego en los bucles donde aumentas los valores llamas a tu nuevo y flamante método:

```
        if (oC.getPolaridad().compareToIgnoreCase("Positivo") == 0) {
            // hpos++; esto no
            oConsLocal.addHpos();
        } else {
            hneg++;// aquí lo mismo - creas el campo en ComentariosDTO, el método...
        }
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Lo resolví sin el método solo con getters y setters porque los datos que recorría del método  TipoEnfermedad están en otra clase (Comentarios DAO), por lo cual utilice un arreglo de objetos, pero esta forma también es buena.  Saludos!